# Stuck on Node + MongoDB asynchronous query issue

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, asynchronous

*A little preface: I am very new to working with Node so please bear with my ignorance*

I am trying to pass some info from an array in Node.js, and check whether it exists in a MongoDB document. I am still struggling to wrap my head around Node and how to work with databases asynchronously.

I have the following code

```
for (i in articleTitle) {

    console.log(articleTitle[i]);

    // Use connect method to connect to the Server 
    MongoClient.connect(mongoUrl, function(err, db) {
        if (err) throw err; // Throw error
        var query = { title: articleTitle[i] }; // Query Parameter

        // Perform Query
        db.collection(mongoCollection).find(query).toArray(function(err, result) {
            if (err) throw err; // Throw error
            if (result == '') {
                console.log('No results found for title:', articleTitle[i]);
            } else {
                console.log('Found an entry');
            }

            db.close(); // Close connection
        });
    });
}
```

In the above code, I have an array of strings called `articleTitle` (for example: `['Title1', 'Title2', 'Title3']`), I then run through each of those titles in the array (using the `for()` loop) to check if each title exists in the database.

The output I get is as follows:

```
> Title1
> Title2
> Title3
> No results found for title: Title 3
> No results found for title: Title 3
> No results found for title: Title 3
```

As evident above it seems to be checking for the last object in the array three times. I have also tried to implement the [async package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/async) but struggled with that as well.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue you have is scope of the variable `i` in the callback function.

Use `for (let i in articleTitle)` instead.
This creates a new variable i for every iteration and scope is restricted to that iteration.

The answers to this question [JavaScript closure inside loops – simple practical example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example) explain in detail about why this happens and about scope and closure in JavaScript. The above question is an exact duplicate of this question.

Comment: That worked perfectly. Thanks for the further information.
(Will mark as answer in 7 minutes ;p)